# Convert nested list of dicts to dict in Ansible

Tags: list, ansible

I'm trying to convert a list of dictionary in dictionary. My defined vars:

```
  users:
  - name: bruce
    age: 22
    params:
      - key: "k1"
        value: "v1bruce"
      - key: "k2"
        value: "v2bruce"
  - name: alan
    age: 25
    params:
      - key: "k1"
        value: "v1alan"
      - key: "k5"
        value: "v5alan"
  - name: carl
    age: 43
    params:
      - key: "k1"
        value: "v1carl"
      - key: "k2"
        value: "v2carl"
      - key: "k5"
        value: "v5carl"
```

I need to create a new structure in Ansible starting from the previous converting params to dictionaries like the following:

```
  employee:
  - name: bruce
    age: 22
    params:
      "k1": "v1bruce"
      "k2": "v2bruce"
  - name: alan
    age: 25
    params:
      "k1": "v1alan"
      "k5": "v5alan"
  - name: carl
    age: 43
    params:
      "k1": "v1carl"
      "k2": "v2carl"
      "k5": "v5carl"
```

The key point is that I don't know how many elements my starting list is composed.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#items2dict-filter) in loop. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        employee: "{{ employee|default([]) +
                      [{'name': item.name,
                        'age': item.age,
                        'params': item.params|items2dict}] }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: ugly solution ahead.

The base to understand is that your `params` looks like a transformation of a dict via the `dict2items` filter. So we have to reverse the operation with `items2dict`. But since it is nested inside your list of hash, it is not so easy. This is what I came up with:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    users:
      - name: bruce
        age: 22
        params:
          - key: "k1"
            value: "v1bruce"
          - key: "k2"
            value: "v2bruce"
      - name: alan
        age: 25
        params:
          - key: "k1"
            value: "v1alan"
          - key: "k5"
            value: "v5alan"
      - name: carl
        age: 43
        params:
          - key: "k1"
            value: "v1carl"
          - key: "k2"
            value: "v2carl"
          - key: "k5"
            value: "v5carl"

  tasks:
    - name: Show raw
      debug:
        var: users

    - name: Transform
      set_fact:
        user_transformed: >-
          {%- set result = [] -%}
          {%- for user in users -%}
            {{
              result.append({
                 'name': user.name,
                 'age': user.age,
                 'params': user.params | items2dict
               })
            }}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ result | to_json | from_json }}

    - name: Show transformed
      debug:
        var: user_transformed
```

Comment: Solution by @vladimir basically does the same thing and is more compact.